# Responsive Navbar in Bootstrap withdropdown Menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar

I'm trying to develop a navbar with bootstrap.
All I want is that if my navbar is collapsed the menu items within the navbar should expand.

Here is my project
http://studi-wgt.de/development/Joomla/jupgrade/

Here is what I want:
http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/navbar-tutorial.php
(navbar at top)